# Latex Wysiwig equation editor to embed into web page

Tags: javascript, html, latex, editor, mathjax

I want to provide a math editor on a webpage.
I have used codecogs for the same.
But I find that the free version at latex.codecogs.com is most of the times unavailable
whereas the paid version is very expensive.

I am still in the development stage, hence don't want to invest huge
Is there any other alternative to codecogs for math wysiwig editor?

Comment: This isn't a question that fits on StackOverflow (see the FAQ to understand why). But have a look at mathlive.io.

Comment: My apologies for mis-posting. Thanks @PeterKrautzberger

Comment: No worries. If you run into issues integrating mathlive, then stackOverflow is a good place to ask detailed questions.